# Why does Google Translate Pronounce '일' like hi'je?

Tags: pronunciation

Google [pronounces](https://translate.google.com/#ko/en/%EC%9D%BC) 일 like [hi'je]. But according to what I've read, `ㅇ` is silent, `ㅣ`is `[i]` and `ㄹ` is `[r/l]` . Shouldn't it be something like `[il]`?

Comment: Warm welcome to Korean SE. You need to note that Google Translate is notorious for its mistakes in recognizing some characters such as 사람 and 사랑 in your previous question and you should never rely on it when learning any language. We have some questions on resources here, [tag: resources](http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and please try to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, unless an 'ㄹ' is doubled, it's a 'soft' **L** sound - somewhere *between* **L** and **R**. "hi'je", as you hear it, may not sound like 'il', but perhaps it's more similar to 'ir' in your mind? Also, try some longer examples, like "일본에 갔어요?". Do they bring out the 'l' a bit more?

Secondly, partly due to the relatively rapid and recent rise of Korea on the international stage, the development of resources on the Korean language may be a little behind some of those on other languages. You are right to be wary of fully trusting any one resource.

Finally, the audio technology used on that site may also be experimental. I find that, on my computer, playback occurs at different speeds each time I press the button - which also affects the impression of what you hear.